# Shopping Cart Page display only one item in Asp.Net Core 2.0 Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

There is  a problem When I clicked on Add to cart Button ,only one item is displayed and previous one is deleted .I have four Boostrap tab,on  every click I am passing tab&id .How to fix this problem I think its  very simple but I am new in  Asp.net Core.Any help it would be great appreciate.Following are more details about my application.

This is my Index.cshtml page

```html
<!--remaing three tabs here same as following-->
<div class="tab4">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.FootwereList)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-3 product-men">
                            <div class="men-pro-item simpleCart_shelfItem">
                                <div class="men-thumb-item">
                                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)" alt="" class="pro-image-front">
                                    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageBack)" alt="" class="pro-image-back">
                                    <div class="men-cart-pro">
                                        <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                            <a asp-page="/single" asp-route-tab="@item.tab" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID" class="link-product-add-cart">Quick View</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <span class="product-new-top">New</span>

                                </div>
                                <div class="item-info-product ">
                                    <h4><a href="single.html">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</a></h4>
                                    <div class="info-product-price">
                                        <span class="item_price">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalPrice)</span>
                                        <del>$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FalsePrice)</del>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="snipcart-details top_brand_home_details item_add single-item hvr-outline-out button2">
                                        <form action="/shopping_Cart" method="post">
                                            
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inner-men-cart-pro">
                                        <a asp-page="/shopping_Cart" asp-route-tab="@item.tab" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID" class="link-product-add-cart">Add to cart</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
```

This is my shopping_cart.cshtml Page

```html
@page
@model EliteShopping.Pages.Shopping.shopping_CartModel
@{
}
<h2 style="position:center;">Your Shopping Cart</h2>

    @*<p>
        <a asp-page="Customer">Create New Customer</a>
    </p>*@
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Image")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayName("Price")
                </th>
              
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.FootwereList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageaFront)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalPrice)
                    </td>
                   
                    <td>
                        <a asp-page="./EditCustomer" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Edit Cart Item</a> |
                        <a asp-page="./AllCustomer" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Delete Item</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is shopping_cart.cs page

```html
using EliteShopping.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using RazorPagesDemo.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EliteShopping.Pages.Shopping
{

    public class shopping_CartModel : PageModel
    {
        DatabaseContext _Context;
        public shopping_CartModel(DatabaseContext databasecontext)
        {
            _Context = databasecontext;
        }
        
        public List<Footwere> FootwereList { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public Footwere Footwere { get; set; }


        public void OnGet(int id, string tab)

        {     //for Footwere
            var Footwere = (from FootwereList in _Context.FootwereTB
                            where FootwereList.ProductID == id & FootwereList.tab == tab
                            select FootwereList).ToList();

            FootwereList = Footwere;
        }

        
      
    }
 }
```

- Pages are conntected to the database.
- All pages are dynamic.

Comment: What is the value of `Footwere.Count` when you debug through the code?

Comment: What do you think `Footwere.ProductID = 0;` does?

Comment: All  the code snippets of `OnPost Handler`  is not working .I've applied different solution on `Footwere.ProductID = 0;`still it's not working,same result is coming without `OnPost Handler`method.

Comment: How to write `OnPost Handler` method  to get expected result.

Comment: I have tried your code and each time you click `Add to Cart`, you will get into the `OnGet` handler which redirects you to the page of your shopping cart.You do not save you choice before you do another click.Could you be more specific about your scenario?Do you need to redirect to Cart view or stay at the Index view after clicking the `Add to Cart` button?Where to invoke the OnPost?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.I need to redirect to Cart View.I am unable to save  choice before another click,I want to save each item to the cart after clicking `Add to Cart`,how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Because with every Get method you assign new footwereList.

```
FootwereList = Footwere;
```

(Also you are assigning  a list to an entity)
Thats why you always have one in the cart. It should be

```
FootwereList.Add(Footwere);
```

also I think you should use either database or session to keep items.Like

```
_Context.SaveChanges();
```

I mean

```
    public void OnGet(int id, string tab)

            {     //for Footwere
               var Footwere = _Context.Footwere.Where(p=>p.ProductID==id).FirstOrDefault() ;
               FootwereList.Add(Footwere);
              _Context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

If you are going to keep them in Database

Comment: I've applyed but it through this error `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

EliteShopping.Pages.Shopping.shopping_CartModel.FootwereList.get returned null.`

Comment: Can you share your DbContext Model?

Comment: sure, here it is `public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        
        public DbSet<Product>ProductTB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<woman> womanTB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bag> BagsTB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Footwere> FootwereTB { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        
    }`

Comment: As far as I understand you will keep them in the "Carts" DbSet so you need to Add those items to your cart item. Of course you need to assign a new "carts" item according to it and then     _Context.Carts.Add(NewcartItem); instead of FootwereList.Add(Footwere); line.

Comment: I've tried already `_Context.Carts.Add(NewcartItem);` instead of `FootwereList.Add(Footwere);` but it 's showing this error `System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'
`

Comment: Then you need to reconsider your "NewcartItem"

Comment: Still I am facing same problem..none of the above solutions helped me.